# How to improve the speed of the float lerp function?

Tags: c++, optimization, graphics, simd

Recently I am writing a soft raster renderer, but it's speed is really so slow. By performance testing, I find that the float lerp function is the bottleneck. How to improve the speed of this function? use simd? Any idea?

```
inline float MathUtil::Lerp(float x1, float x2, float t)
{
    return x1 + (x2 - x1)*t;
}

//lerp vector
ZCVector MathUtil::Lerp(const ZCVector& v1, const ZCVector& v2, float t)
{
    return ZCVector(
        Lerp(v1.x, v2.x, t),
        Lerp(v1.y, v2.y, t),
        Lerp(v1.z, v2.z, t),
        v1.w
    );
}

//lerp ZCFLOAT2
ZCFLOAT2 MathUtil::Lerp(const ZCFLOAT2& v1, const ZCFLOAT2& v2, float t)
{
    return ZCFLOAT2(
        Lerp(v1.u, v2.u, t),
        Lerp(v1.v, v2.v, t)
    );
}

//lerp ZCFLOAT3
ZCFLOAT3 MathUtil::Lerp(const ZCFLOAT3& v1, const ZCFLOAT3& v2, float t)
{
    return ZCFLOAT3(
        Lerp(v1.x, v2.x, t),
        Lerp(v1.y, v2.y, t),
        Lerp(v1.z, v2.z, t)
    );
}

//lerp VertexOut
VertexOut MathUtil::Lerp(const VertexOut& v1, const VertexOut& v2, float t)
{
    return VertexOut(
        Lerp(v1.posTrans, v2.posTrans, t),
        Lerp(v1.posH, v2.posH, t),
        Lerp(v1.tex, v2.tex, t),
        Lerp(v1.normal, v2.normal, t),
        Lerp(v1.color, v2.color, t),
        Lerp(v1.oneDivZ, v2.oneDivZ, t)
    );
}
```

the structure of VertexOut:

```
class VertexOut
{
public:

    ZCVector posTrans;

    ZCVector posH;

    ZCFLOAT2 tex;

    ZCVector normal;

    ZCFLOAT3 color;

    float oneDivZ;
}
```

the `scanlinefill` function to fill triangle, every vertex needs to use lerp function, so it will be called so many times.

```
void Tiny3DDeviceContext::ScanlineFill(const VertexOut& left, const VertexOut& right,  int yIndex)
{
    float dx = right.posH.x - left.posH.x;

    for (float x = left.posH.x; x <= right.posH.x; x += 0.5f)
    {
        int xIndex = static_cast<int>(x + .5f);
        if(xIndex >= 0 && xIndex < m_pDevice->GetClientWidth())
        {

            float lerpFactor = 0;
            if (dx != 0)
            {
                lerpFactor = (x - left.posH.x) / dx;
            }


            float oneDivZ = MathUtil::Lerp(left.oneDivZ, right.oneDivZ, lerpFactor);
            if (oneDivZ >= m_pDevice->GetZ(xIndex,yIndex))
            {
                m_pDevice->SetZ(xIndex, yIndex, oneDivZ);
                //lerp get vertex
                VertexOut out = MathUtil::Lerp(left, right, lerpFactor);
                out.posH.y = yIndex;

                m_pDevice->DrawPixel(xIndex, yIndex, m_pShader->PS(out));
            }           
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Try bitwise fiddling maybe. Don't try premature optimizations in the wrong place.

Comment: What platform are you optimizing for?  x86?  Do you need a binary that runs on older CPUs, or can you use AVX and FMA?  What compiler and options?  Even more important, what's the surrounding code?  Does it actually auto-vectorize?  This function itself should vectorize trivially with SSE or any other SIMD ISA.  The surrounding code that this inlines into is obviously critical.  Is latency the limiting factor for  throughput?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Integer bit-fiddling between FP instructions isn't usually a good idea on modern CPUs.  On x86, you need to either do it with SIMD integer instructions (since even scalar floats use XMM registers), or you have to do a slow round trip between XMM and integer registers.  There are extra bypass delays from using integer vector instructions between FP insns, so even if you could do something useful with one or two integer instructions, it would be worse latency than just using FP.  Besides, vector FP instructions are extremely high throughput.  e.g. 2 vector FMAs per clock on Haswell.

Comment: @PeterCordes I never told this would be a _good idea_ :P

Comment: Environment ：win10, vs2015. It is used to lerp pos,tex,color and so on, how to rewrite it if use SIMD?

Comment: [edit] your question to include those details, and *much* more detail on the loop that calls this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This loop structure potentially runs `lerp` twice as many times as needed:

```
for (float x = left.posH.x; x <= right.posH.x; x += 0.5f) {
      int xIndex = static_cast<int>(x + .5f);
      ...
}
```

Instead, (and more accurately), loop by incrementing integer `xIndex`, and calculate the right `float x` for each `xIndex`.

---

This might auto-vectorize, but you'd have to check your compiler output to see what happened.  Hopefully the Lerp that you overwrite with `out.posH.y = yIndex;` gets optimized away since you discard the result.  If not, you might get a speedup from making a wrapper function that doesn't do that Lerp.

---

You could make it more SIMD-friendly by using a Struct-of-Arrays approach instead of your AoS approach that keeps everything for a struct contiguous.  However, you're Lerping multiple elements the same way, so it might auto-vectorize with two scalar and one vector Lerp.

See the [sse](/questions/tagged/sse) tag wiki for some guides to SIMD stuff, including a link to this [very nice beginner / intermediate set of slides](https://deplinenoise.wordpress.com/2015/03/06/slides-simd-at-insomniac-games-gdc-2015/).

---

There are probably other things you could change, too, esp. **bigger restructuring of your code to do less overall work**.  This kind of optimization can more often give you even bigger speedups than using SIMD to efficiently apply the brute force of modern CPUs.

Doing both at once to multiply the speedups is what really makes things fast.

Cache misses and memory-bandwidth bottlenecks are often a huge factor, so optimizing your access patterns can make a big difference.

See [Agner Fog's optimization guide](http://www.agner.org/optimize/) if you want to learn about more low-level details.  He has a C++ optimization guide, but most of the good stuff is about x86 asm.  (See also the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki).  But remember, this low-level optimization stuff is only a good idea *after* looking for high-level optimizations.